# Can you help explain this Held-Karp TSP Pseudocode?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, traveling-salesman

I am trying to implement the Held-Karp algorithm for the Traveling Salesman Problem by following this pseudocode:

[image]

(which I found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm#Example.5B4.5D )

I can do the algorithm by hand but am having trouble actually implementing it in code. It would be great if someone could provide an easy-to-follow explanation.

---

I also don't understand this:

[image]

I thought this part was for setting the distance from the starting city to it's connected cities. If that was the case, wouldn't it be it `C({1}, k) := d1,k` and not `C({k}, k) := d1,k`? Am I just completely misunderstanding this?

I have also heard that this algorithm does not perform very well past about 15-20 cities so for around 40 cities, what would be a good alternative?

Comment: 40 cities isn't a lot in the grand scheme, but you do have to decide how you want to trade off predictability of running time against solution quality.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat hmmm okay, that's good to know. Would you say Held-Karp is viable for 40 cities then or not?

Comment: No, it's not a great choice. I'd probably reach for a mixed integer program at that scale, but if you need to guarantee running time, 2-opt or another local search algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Held-Karp is a [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) approach.

In dynamic programming, you break the task into subtasks and use "dynamic function" to solve larger subtasks using already computed results of smaller subtasks, until you finally solve your task.

To understand a DP algorithm it's imperative to understand how it defines subtask and dynamic function.

In the case of Held-Karp, the subtask is following:

> For a given set of vertices `S` and a vertex `k`   (`1 ∉ S`, `k ∈ S`)
>
> `C(S,k)` is the minimal length of the path that starts with vertex `1`, traverses all vertices in `S` and ends with the vertex `k`.

Given this subtask definition, it's clear why initialization is:

```
C({k}, k) := d(1,k)
```

The minimal length of the path from `1` to `k`, traversing through `{k}`, is just the edge from `1` to `k`.

---

Next, the "dynamic function".

A side note, DP algorithm could be written as [top-down or bottom-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_and_bottom-up_design). This pseudocode is bottom-up, meaning it computes smaller tasks first and uses their results for larger tasks. To be more specific, it computes tasks in the order of increasing size of the set `S`, starting from `|S|=1` and going up to `|S| = n-1` (i.e. `S` containing all vertices, except `1`).

Now, consider a task, defined by some `S, k`. Remember, it corresponds to path from `1`, through `S`, ending in `k`.

We break it into a:

- path from  `1`, through all vertices in `S` except `k` (`S\k`), which ends in the vertex `m`   (`m ∈ S`, `m ≠ k`):   `C(S\k, m)`
- an edge from `m` to `k`

It's easy to see, that if we look through all possible ways to break `C(S,k)` like this, and find the minimal path among them, we'll have the answer for `C(S, k)`.

---

Finally, having computed all `C(S, k)` for `|S| = n-1`, we check all of them, completing the cycle with the missing edge from `k` to `1`:   `d(1,k)`. The minimal cycle is the final result.

---

Regarding:

> I have also heard that this algorithm does not perform very well past about 15-20 cities so for around 40 cities, what would be a good alternative?

Held-Karp has algorithmic complexity of θ(n²2<sup>n</sup>). 40² * 2<sup>40</sup> ≈ 1.75 * 10<sup>15</sup> which, I would say, is unfeasible to compute on a single machine in reasonable time.

As David Eisenstat suggested, there are approaches using [mixed integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) that can solve this problem fast enough for N=40.

For example, see [this blog post](https://opensourc.es/blog/mip-tsp/), and [this project](https://github.com/ericphanson/TravelingSalesmanExact.jl) that builds upon it.

Comment: Solving a mixed integer program will give you the optimal solution, likely quite fast for 40 cities unless there's something weird going on. But there's no guarantee.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, can you please provide a link to back that claim? I understand that it's possible to describe TSP as an integer programming problem, but I'm not sure that solving such problem would be faster than dedicated DP-based algorithm.

Comment: https://opensourc.es/blog/mip-tsp/, for example.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, thank you. I found [this project](https://github.com/ericphanson/TravelingSalesmanExact.jl) that uses your link as a source. The have benchmarks for exact and approximate solutions for N=48 and N=50, so I think that proves that these methods can be faster in practice.

Comment: @Aivean so just to clarify, was I correct in thinking that it should be C({1}, k) := d(1,k) and not C({k}, k) := d1,k in the pseudocode?

But thank you for that fantastic explanation of Held-Karp, that'll help a lot!

Comment: @bloo, sorry my typo. `C(S, k)` is the minimal length of the path from `1` to `k`, traversing through `S`,  so for `S ={k}`, `C(S, k)` is just the edge from `1` to `k`.